# How to convert 3 angles to a vector

Tags: opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Euler angles to directional vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568568/how-to-convert-euler-angles-to-directional-vector)

I'm using OpenGL to rotate a brick. The brick simulates a phone that has an accelerometer. The initial vector I'm using is (0.0, 0.0,-1.0)

```
glRotatef(angle.x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(angle.y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(angle.z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

How do I get the accelerometer's vector from the angles above?

Comment: I need yaw pitch and roll. The first formula does not have roll. Also the code below it is in a matrix. I need a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you have to multiply your initial vector by the 3 matrices you mention ? Just replicating the way OpenGL does it.

This wouldn't be the most efficient, but this would give the resulting vector. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Okay I got it working. I tried using the rotation matrices in my OpenGL Red book but it did not work. I tried the matrix code mentioned above and it worked. I just multiplied the vector by the matrix's third column of the XYZ rotation formula. One interesting thing is that I had to use -M_PI instead of -1.0 for the starting vector. I then normalized it so that it's minimum is -1.0 and maximum is 1.0 for any axis.